# Como puedo ver las funciones de un modulo en python?

Tags: python-3.7

Ejemplo yo quiero saber que hacen las funciones del modulo sys

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow en español. Te recomendaría darte un [tour] para que veas cómo funciona el sitio y de paso ganes tu primera medalla. Generalmente las preguntas que tienen mayor información de contexto o que aportan código utilizado para llegar a la solución tienen mayor aceptación. Por favor [edit] tu pregunta y agregar mayor información de contexto, revisa [ask] y [repro]

Comment: ¿Has investigado un poco?

Comment: si, pero no encuentro esa explicacion, soy principiante en python, seria de gran utilidad que alguien me explicara eso...

Answer (score 4):

Tienes al menos tres vías:

- Acudir a la [documentación online](https://docs.python.org/3/) de Python, que es muy completa. En ella tienes descritos todos los módulos, las funciones en cada uno de ellos, a veces ejemplos de código, etc. En concreto [aqui está la del módulo sys](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#module-sys)
- Usar la ayuda interna de Python. Abre un intérprete (es decir, lanza el comando python o python3 en una terminal) y dentro de él ejecuta lo siguiente:

  ```
  >>> import sys
  >>> help(sys)
  NAME
      sys

  MODULE REFERENCE
      https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/sys.html

      The following documentation is automatically generated from the Python
      source files.  It may be incomplete, incorrect or include features that
      are considered implementation detail and may vary between Python
      implementations.  When in doubt, consult the module reference at the
      location listed above.

  DESCRIPTION
      This module provides access to some objects used or maintained by the
      interpreter and to functions that interact strongly with the interpreter.
  ...etc...
  ```

  Obtienes una descripción de cada una de las funciones del módulo.
- Si sólo quieres saber  qué símbolos están definidos en ese módulo, puedes usar la función `dir()` para obtener la lista de ellos. Después puedes usar `help()` sobre alguno de sus resultados. Por ejemplo:

  ```
  >>> import sys
  >>> dir(sys)

  ['__displayhook__', '__doc__', '__excepthook__', '__interactivehook__',
   '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', '__stderr__', 
  '__stdin__', '__stdout__', '_clear_type_cache', '_current_frames', 
  '_debugmallocstats', '_getframe', '_home', '_mercurial', '_xoptions', 
  'abiflags', 'api_version', 'argv', 'base_exec_prefix', 'base_prefix', 
  'builtin_module_names', 'byteorder', 'call_tracing', 'callstats', 'copyright', 
  'displayhook', 'dont_write_bytecode', 'exc_info', 'excepthook', 'exec_prefix', 
  'executable', 'exit', 'flags', 'float_info', 'float_repr_style', 
  'get_coroutine_wrapper', 'getallocatedblocks', 'getcheckinterval', 
  'getdefaultencoding', 'getdlopenflags', 'getfilesystemencoding', 'getprofile', 
  'getrecursionlimit', 'getrefcount', 'getsizeof', 'getswitchinterval', 
  'gettrace', 'hash_info', 'hexversion', 'implementation', 'int_info', 'intern', 
  'is_finalizing', 'maxsize', 'maxunicode', 'meta_path', 'modules', 'path', 
  'path_hooks', 'path_importer_cache', 'platform', 'prefix', 'ps1', 'ps2', 
  'set_coroutine_wrapper', 'setcheckinterval', 'setdlopenflags', 'setprofile', 
  'setrecursionlimit', 'setswitchinterval', 'settrace', 'stderr', 'stdin', 
  'stdout', 'thread_info', 'version', 'version_info', 'warnoptions']

  >>> help(sys.exit)

  exit(...)
      exit([status])

      Exit the interpreter by raising SystemExit(status).
      If the status is omitted or None, it defaults to zero (i.e., success).
      If the status is an integer, it will be used as the system exit status.
      If it is another kind of object, it will be printed and the system
      exit status will be one (i.e., failure).
  ```

No obstante, ten presente que lo que te sale con `dir(sys)` es la lista de todos los símbolos, y no sólo de las funciones. Así, por ejemplo, sale `sys.path` que no es una función, sino una lista. Por ello si hicieras `help(sys.path)` no obtendrías una explicación de para qué sirve esa lista, sino la documentación del tipo `list`. Por eso es mejor usar la documentación online donde se describen no sólo las funciones, sino también las variables.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias amigo